# Jquery selecting from within object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have alternate color theme in a table. But, I will need to break this ie. change the pattern if some condition is true then that row will be given same color as previous row.

The situation is that some row might have subheading( or rather sub-row which is related ) and so has to have same color of the above associated row.

This pattern is not fixed, so the nth equation approach doesn't work.

```
$('something').each(function(){
     ($(this)>'somethingelse').each(function(){
           some css class of previous row enforced
     }
}
```

I'd also be delighted if someone can tell me a method to a jquery function that return present css value of an element.

Comment: To retrieve CSS properties: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: and use `prev()` to get the previous item in jQuery => http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: You will probably have to explain what type of elements are "something" and "somethingelse". That would put us in a better position to help you

Comment: see if this can help you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kaEwq

Comment: Something would refer to a class used to identify the element.

Answer (score 0):

To get the css value of an attribute, you just use the .css( attributeName ) method.

For example, if you want the current height of id='test', you can get the value like so:

```
$('#test').css('height');
```

Or set the value like so:

```
$('#test').css('height', '50px');
```

More info here:  http://api.jquery.com/css/